# In vs code sometimes when I type a css attribute emmet gives me really unhelpful suggestions

Tags: visual-studio-code, intellisense, emmet

In vs code sometimes when I type a css attribute emmet gives me really unhelpful suggestions. Is there any way to exclude certain suggestions or change the way this behaves?

For example in my stylesheet I am adding `margin: 0`. If I type `margin0` Emmet suggests `max-resolution: 0;`. I don't think I have ever used max-resolution but I use margin all the time. I could cite many other examples of what I consider unhelpful suggestions. Any ideas to make this work better?

[screenshot of unhelpful suggestion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AtmKq.png)